# Warning: comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, file, fopen

I started learning C language and my task is to write a script that will check the text in the txt file for the presence of the word ananas, but you can’t use `strlen(), strcpy(), strcmp()`.  I wrote code that doesn’t work, but the output is simple 0. I understand why it outputs something, but I don’t understand how to do it so it worked fine.
And when I compile the code, I get this error

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
if(c[i] == s || ss){
```

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() {
  FILE *f;
  char c[1000];
  char a[] = {'a'};
  char aa[] = {'A'};

  char n[] = {'n'};
  char nn[] = {'N'};

  char s[] = {'s'};
  char ss[] = {'S'};
  int g = 0;
  int col = 0;

  
  f = fopen("bananas1.txt", "r");
  fgets(c, 1000, f);
  for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    for(int q = 0; q < 1;){
      if(c[i] == a || aa){
        q++;
      }
      if(c[i] == n || nn){
        q++;
      }
      if(c[i] == s || ss){
        q++;
      }
      if(q == 1){
        g++;
        q = 0;
      }
      if(q == 0){
        g = 0;
      }

    }
    if(g == 6){
      col++;
    }

  }
  printf("%d", col);
  fclose(f);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the text that I need to check in the `bananas1.txt` file

> Bananas are edible fruits, botanically berries. In some countries, bAnAnAs used for cooking are called plantains, distinguishing them from dessert bananaS. The fruits grow in clusters hanging from the top of the plant. Almost all modern edible seedless BANANAS come from two wild species of Musa acuminata and Musa balbisiana. The scientific names of most cultivated bananas are Musa acuminata, Musa balbisiana, and Musa X paradisiaca, depending on their genomic constitution.

As you can see, there is the word bananas, and it contains the word bananas; I need to count the number of ananas words in this text.

Comment: Why not write your own of `strstr`?

Comment: this is my homework, sorry

Comment: Why not utilise the ```toupper``` function from ```ctype``` header files, so you only need to check once?

Comment: There's no need of arrays of characters here in your code. Just use ```char a = `a`; ```. I suggest using more expressive variable names.

Comment: If you retain the arrays for the single characters you're reading, you need to modify `if(c[i] == a || aa){` to `if (c[i] == a[0] || c[i] == aa[0])`.  That will fix the compilation warning.  However, it isn't obvious what you're doing in the rest of the algorithm — there are probably improvements to be made.  If the text contained "anananas", would your algorithm work?  Should it?  Since you seem to be OK with "bananas" being selected as an example of "ananas", it presumably should be OK with "anananas" too.  Write and use your own case-insensitive version of `strstr()`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this

```
 if(c[i] == a || aa){
```

is meaning to say

"if c[i] is either 'a' or 'aa' then ..."

Sadly, C doesn't work like that. The attempt to compare a char (c[i) with an array of chars (a, even though it's only one character) is why you are getting the error.

You need

```
  if(c[i] == 'a')....
```

or

```
 char a = 'a';
 if(c[i] == a)...
```

there is no way to look to see if one char is equal to 2 chars (!). If you need to look for 'aa' then you have to look for an a then look at the next char too

Also you cannot do shortcut 'ors'

```
  if(c[i] == 'a' || 'b')
```

does not say "if c[i] == a or c[i] == b".